# Symfony2 & Doctrine2 - automatically insert/update key-value rows

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm learning Symfony2 with Doctrine, so i'm new at it.
This is my issue: I've got Users table with 'statusId' column (just example, much more like that in my project). I also have DictStatus table with 'id' and 'name' columns (id => name == key => value). Is it possible in doctrine2 to add some constants (like: const ACTIVE = 1;) to my DictStatus mapping, so that it would be automatically inserted or updated in database as row with id='1' and name='ACTIVE'?

If that would be impossible could I extract constants with http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getconstants.php, prepare inserts and run my script automatically with 
doctrine:schema:update --force

Or what about not using DictTable and keeping my Statuses only hardcoded as constants? Would that be unelegant or sopmething ;) ?

Answer (score 1):

If the status is just a scalar value, I would recommend not to create a separate entity for it. This will save you a huge amount of DB queries later. The most efficient way would be to handle it as integer.

If you feel safer with constants, you can implement them as properties of the entity class.

```
<?php

namespace Your\SomethingBundle\Entity;

use \Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Foobar
{
    const STATUS_GREAT = 1;
    const STATUS_NOTSOGREAT = 0;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $status;


    public function setStatus($status)
    {
        $this->status = $status;
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
$myFoobar = new Foobar();
$myFoobar->setStatus(Foobar::STATUS_GREAT);
```

Validation of the `$status` value can be done in the setter itself or via a [Validator annotation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html).